# SQL Query optimization 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have a table named `SnackMaster`. Its structure is given below :

```
SnackID        int
SnackName      varchar(100)
SnackAmount    decimal(18,2)
```

e.g :

```
SnacksID     : 1
SnacksName   : Tea
SnacksAmount : 10.00
```

And there is another table named `SnacksOrderDetais` which contains snacks orders from employees. It's structure is given below:

```
OrderID        int
EmployeeID     int  
SnackCount     tinyint
TotalAmount    decimal(18,2)
orderDate      date
```

e.g :

```
OrderID      : 1,
EmployeeID   : 1,
SnackCount   : 2 (two cup tea),
TotalAMount  : 20 (2*10),
OrderDate    : 2014-02-14

OrderID      : 2,
EmployeeID   : 2,
SnackCount   : 2 (two cup tea),
TotalAMount  :  20 (2*10),
OrderDate    : 2014-02-14
```

I need a Snacks summary like the following:

```
SnacksName   : Tea,
SnackCount   : 4 (that is 2 each from the above two orders),
TotalAmount  : 40 (twenty from each orders)
```

I used the following query to get the result. The result is ok but i want to know if there is any other optimized query available?

```
SELECT DISTINCT SOD.SnacksID
    ,SnacksName
    ,(SELECT SUM(SnacksCount) 
      FROM SnacksOrderDetails 
      WHERE SnacksID = SOD.SnacksID ) AS SnacksCount
FROM SnacksOrderDetails SOD
INNER JOIN SnacksMaster SM ON SOD.SnacksID = SM.SnacksID
WHERE SOD.OrderedOn = @OrderDate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, clarify the distinction between TotalAmount  and SnackCount

Here for a start:

```
SELECT SM.SnacksName,
        SUM(SOD.SnacksCount) AS SnacksCount
FROM SnacksMaster SM 
INNER JOIN SnacksOrderDetails SOD ON SOD.SnacksID = SM.SnacksID AND SOD.OrderedOn = @OrderDate
GROUP BY SM.SnacksName
```

Answer (score 1):

Use GROUP BY to obtain the same. Something like this:

```
SELECT SOD.SnacksID, SnacksName, SUM(SnacksCount) AS SnacksCount 
FROM SnacksOrderDetails SOD 
INNER JOIN SnacksMaster SM ON SOD.SnacksID = SM.SnacksID 
WHERE SOD.OrderedOn = @OrderDate
GROUP BY SOD.SnacksID
```

Comment: Yes..Correct. Somehow overlooked it. Correcting now.